# How to display FieldSet label and its value in PageBlockTable

Tags: apex, visualforce, fieldsets

I am having a Custom Object (Say MyCustomObj).It has fields A,B,C,D,E. I have created a Fieldset and added A,B,C fields for MyCustomObj.

By using Dynamic SOQL I got the values of all fields including fieldset and stored it in a list. That means this list has all values of A,B,C fields of MyCustomObj.

Now I want to populate those values in a Repeater in a VF Page.

How I will display?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several examples if you google "Fieldsets in Visualforce".

Here's a nice tutorial from our own SSE guru Bob Buzzard:

http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2011/02/visualforce-field-sets.html

```
 <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Account.FieldSets.General}" 
                    var="field">
              <apex:inputField value="{!Account[field]}" />
           </apex:repeat>
```

Comment: Example is good. But there all fields are displayed as input field.

But I want to display all fields in PageBlockTable in Page.

Comment: @Rudra_NoVoice The same principle still applies. Just put the loop within a pageBlockSection

Comment: Again, after a quick google search, the following example shows up: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/245/dynamic-number-of-columns-in-a-pageblocktable

Comment: Rudra_NoVoice the example shows how to can access it. you just need to modify the code to use different components than the Inputs.

Comment: its the same concept, just different tags... and the {!Account[field]} part doesn't need to be in anything (it can be just that, with out the apex:input etc)

Comment: @SalesForceGirl: What does account mean here in attribute value="{!account[f]}".
I'm trying to fetch fields from a custiom Object not from a standard object like Account.

Comment: I was just going off the example from the link in the answer (b/c they were using the account object) in yours it might be {!MyCustomObj[field]}

Answer (score 0):

You can find some information in spec (for example how display field label in page): 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_field_sets.htm

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
<apex:pageBlock title="Fields in Proper Names">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!$ObjectType.Contact.FieldSets.properNames}" var="f">
        <apex:column value="{!f}">
            <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
        </apex:column> 
        <apex:column value="{!f.Label}">
            <apex:facet name="header">Label</apex:facet>
        </apex:column> 
        <apex:column value="{!f.Type}" >
            <apex:facet name="header">Data Type</apex:facet>
        </apex:column> 
    </apex:pageBlockTable> 
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Please answer more than an URL, at minimum include the relevant parts in your answer so that your answers remains meaningful even if the external source may go offline.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke While this is true, it's somewhat ironic considering the accepted (and popular) answer made the same error.