# how to display a table with dynamic columns in vf page based on the selection of picklist?

Tags: visualforce, dynamic, table, column

My picklist values:

1. model,version
2. model,version,option
3. model,version,option,discount

If I choose "model,version" the table displayed with 2 columns like model,version.

If I choose "model,version,option" the table displayed with 3 columns named model,version,option and so on

Please can any one suggest me..

Comment: Closed as unclear? Seems perfectly clear to me. Just what I want to know.

Answer (score 1):

You can take help of from [here](http://forceguru.blogspot.in/2012/11/page-block-table-with-dynamic-columns.html)

Page Block Tables actually support  tags (This was not originally supported). The following example demonstrates 2 ways of accomplishing dynamic columns in a table depending on the type of data you supply.

Using fieldsets is the simplest way to control dynamic columns. This is the best choice if displaying a table of SObjects

```
<apex:pageBlock id="block">
    <apex:pageBlockTable id="table" var="account" value="{!accounts}">
        <apex:column headerValue="Account Name" value="{!account.Name}" />
        <apex:repeat var="f" value="{!$ObjectType.Account.FieldSets.Example_Fieldset}">
            <apex:column headerValue="{!f.label}">
                <apex:inputField value="{!account[f]}" />
            </apex:column>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

If you are using a List, there is an important gotcha with dynamic tables: header cells are not rendered. The fix is to declare the following css snippet and apply the style as outlined below

    .empty-column-content {
        display: none;
    }

You can also use this approach. more information can be found [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/246/11239)

Comment: Incorrect parameter type for subscript. Expected Number, received Text

Answer (score 1):

In your controller:

```
public String picklistValue {get; set;}
public String[] getFields() {
    return picklistValue.split(',');
}
```

then in the page the columns displayed can be driven by the SObject field API names:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable var="sob" value="{!sobs}">
    <apex:repeat var="f" value="{!fields}">
        <apex:column value="{!sob[f]}"/>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

You will need to re-render the table when the picklist changes (use e.g. an `onchange` [apex:actionSupport](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm)).

Also unless you are using an object for which the API names of the fields are OK to display in the picklist, you will need to map from a label shown in the picklist (e.g. "Version") to the API name (e.g. "Version__c").