# Dynamic columns and rows as columns in pageblock or datatable

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocktable

I have a `pageblock table` and its the most basic version at that. The requirement is to have dynamic columns based on the values of a particular field value and other columns grouped below this one.

For eg. my data is like this:

[image: Existing data]

I want the output as:
[image: Required Output]

And similarly if there are more accounts/fields, they should be grouped and displayed accordingly.
Could someone please guide as to how to proceed on this?

Comment: Did you try looking into 'apex:dynamicComponent' ?

Answer (score 2):

You might need to create a wrapper class to represent a row of your table. It will have a list of headers(dates), list of account names and statuses. Then you can put all your data in a collection of such wrappers and display it with apex:repeat check [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/245/dynamic-number-of-columns-in-a-pageblocktable) link for more details on dynamic columns.